Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS shutdown trouble
I have Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS running on a Lenovo ThinkPad E560. Ubuntu is installed on an external USB SD drive. I had no problems for several years.
I have installed the last updates of the system on Monday 19th of August 2024. Since this update, the laptop does not completely shut down anymore.
The system stops, all screens are turned off. But the red light indicating that the system is running is still on. The only way to shut it completely down is pushing the power button during five seconds.
I have checked the logs (journalctrl) and it seems that all steps of the shutdown process are executed successfully. The disks are correctly unmounted.
Is there something I can do to investigate/solve the problem?

Update 2024-08-26
This is the content of the history.log file:
Start-Date: 2024-08-19  21:51:24
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.117'
Install: linux-tools-common:amd64 (5.15.0-118.128, automatic), linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-modules-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), hwdata:amd64 (0.357-1, automatic), linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-tools-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic)
Upgrade: libreoffice-calc:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-gnome:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), uno-libs-private:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-base-core:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-pdfimport:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-core:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (127.0.6533.99-1, 127.0.6533.119-1), libreoffice-common:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), ure:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), busybox-static:amd64 (1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3, 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1), linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1, 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3), libreoffice-draw:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libuno-cppu3:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-impress:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), gnome-shell:amd64 (42.9-0ubuntu2.1, 42.9-0ubuntu2.2), libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), fonts-opensymbol:amd64 (2:102.12+LibO7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 2:102.12+LibO7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.481.2, 1.481.3), postgresql-client-14:amd64 (14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 14.13-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libreoffice-style-colibre:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-writer:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libuno-salhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-style-breeze:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), busybox-initramfs:amd64 (1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3, 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1), linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1, 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3), linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1, 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3), gnome-shell-common:amd64 (42.9-0ubuntu2.1, 42.9-0ubuntu2.2), libreoffice-help-common:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), python3-uno:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libuno-sal3:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-ogltrans:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), ubuntu-standard:amd64 (1.481.2, 1.481.3), ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 (1.481.2, 1.481.3), code:amd64 (1.92.1-1723066302, 1.92.2-1723660989), libreoffice-style-yaru:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-math:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-gtk3:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-help-en-us:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), libreoffice-style-elementary:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5, 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6), intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20240514.0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 3.20240813.0ubuntu0.22.04.2), ubuntu-minimal:amd64 (1.481.2, 1.481.3), liborc-0.4-0:amd64 (1:0.4.32-2, 1:0.4.32-2ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2024-08-19  21:54:14
Start-Date: 2024-08-19  21:54:28
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.117'
Remove: linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-41-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2), linux-headers-6.5.0-41-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2), linux-modules-6.5.0-41-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2), linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2), linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-41:amd64 (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2)
End-Date: 2024-08-19  21:54:38
This is the content of the term.log file:
Log started: 2024-08-19  21:51:24
(Reading database ...
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 291339 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-google-chrome-stable_127.0.6533.119-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (127.0.6533.119-1) over (127.0.6533.99-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-ubuntu-minimal_1.481.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-minimal (1.481.3) over (1.481.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-busybox-static_1%3a1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking busybox-static (1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1) over (1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-ubuntu-standard_1.481.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-standard (1.481.3) over (1.481.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-busybox-initramfs_1%3a1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking busybox-initramfs (1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1) over (1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-code_1.92.2-1723660989_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code (1.92.2-1723660989) over (1.92.1-1723066302) ...
Error in file "/usr/share/applications/AESCrypt.desktop": "all/allfiles" is an invalid MIME type ("all" is an unregistered media type)
Preparing to unpack .../06-fonts-opensymbol_2%3a102.12+LibO7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-opensymbol (2:102.12+LibO7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (2:102.12+LibO7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-gnome-shell_42.9-0ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-shell (42.9-0ubuntu2.2) over (42.9-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-gnome-shell-common_42.9-0ubuntu2.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-shell-common (42.9-0ubuntu2.2) over (42.9-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package hwdata.
Preparing to unpack .../09-hwdata_0.357-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking hwdata (0.357-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-liborc-0.4-0_1%3a0.4.32-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liborc-0.4-0:amd64 (1:0.4.32-2ubuntu0.1) over (1:0.4.32-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-libuno-sal3_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuno-sal3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-libuno-salhelpergcc3-3_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-libuno-cppu3_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuno-cppu3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-ure_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ure (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-uno-libs-private_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking uno-libs-private (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-libreoffice-calc_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-calc (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../19-libreoffice-impress_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-impress (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../20-libreoffice-draw_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-draw (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../21-libreoffice-math_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-math (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../22-libreoffice-help-en-us_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-help-en-us (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../23-libreoffice-help-common_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-help-common (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../24-libreoffice-common_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../25-libreoffice-gnome_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-gnome (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../26-libreoffice-gtk3_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-gtk3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../27-libreoffice-base-core_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-base-core (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../28-python3-uno_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-uno (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../29-libreoffice-writer_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-writer (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../30-libreoffice-core_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-core (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../31-libreoffice-style-colibre_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-colibre (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../32-libreoffice-style-breeze_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-breeze (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../33-libreoffice-style-elementary_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-elementary (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../34-libreoffice-style-yaru_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-yaru (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-6.8.0-40-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../35-linux-modules-6.8.0-40-generic_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../36-linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-40-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../37-linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-40-generic_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../38-intel-microcode_3.20240813.0ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking intel-microcode (3.20240813.0ubuntu0.22.04.2) over (3.20240514.0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../39-linux-generic-hwe-22.04_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) over (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../40-linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) over (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40.
Preparing to unpack .../41-linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../42-linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../43-linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) over (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-common.
Preparing to unpack .../44-linux-tools-common_5.15.0-118.128_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (5.15.0-118.128) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40.
Preparing to unpack .../45-linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-6.8.0-40-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../46-linux-tools-6.8.0-40-generic_6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../47-postgresql-client-14_14.13-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-client-14 (14.13-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../48-ubuntu-desktop-minimal_1.481.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-desktop-minimal (1.481.3) over (1.481.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../49-ubuntu-desktop_1.481.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-desktop (1.481.3) over (1.481.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../50-libreoffice-ogltrans_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-ogltrans (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../51-libreoffice-pdfimport_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-pdfimport (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) over (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5) ...
Setting up code (1.92.2-1723660989) ...
Error in file "/usr/share/applications/AESCrypt.desktop": "all/allfiles" is an invalid MIME type ("all" is an unregistered media type)
Setting up google-chrome-stable (127.0.6533.119-1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-minimal (1.481.3) ...
Setting up intel-microcode (3.20240813.0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
intel-microcode: microcode will be updated at next boot
Setting up libuno-sal3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up gnome-shell-common (42.9-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-14 (14.13-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-modules-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Setting up hwdata (0.357-1) ...
Setting up libreoffice-style-colibre (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up busybox-static (1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up liborc-0.4-0:amd64 (1:0.4.32-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libreoffice-style-breeze (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up busybox-initramfs (1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-style-yaru (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Setting up linux-tools-common (5.15.0-118.128) ...
Setting up linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Setting up fonts-opensymbol (2:102.12+LibO7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Setting up libreoffice-style-elementary (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-118-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Setting up ubuntu-standard (1.481.3) ...
Setting up libuno-cppu3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up linux-tools-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Setting up linux-generic-hwe-22.04 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
Setting up libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up uno-libs-private (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up ure (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-common (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-core (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-math (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-gtk3 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-pdfimport (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-draw (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-help-common (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-gnome (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-impress (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-base-core (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-help-en-us (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up python3-uno (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-ogltrans (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-calc (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Setting up libreoffice-writer (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.6) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.13.1-4.2ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb1
I: (UUID=a8873c88-4f5f-4875-a8f3-7bf435e38e67)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Setting up gnome-shell (42.9-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-desktop-minimal (1.481.3) ...
Setting up ubuntu-desktop (1.481.3) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb1
I: (UUID=a8873c88-4f5f-4875-a8f3-7bf435e38e67)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file /etc/default/grub' Sourcing file /etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-118-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
Log ended: 2024-08-19  21:54:14
Log started: 2024-08-19  21:54:28
(Reading database ...
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 329413 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-6.5.0-41-generic (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2) ...
Removing linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-41 (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2) ...
Removing linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-41-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file /etc/default/grub' Sourcing file /etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-118-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
Removing linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-41-generic (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2) ...
Removing linux-modules-6.5.0-41-generic (6.5.0-41.41~22.04.2) ...
Log ended: 2024-08-19  21:54:38

Review your /var/log/apt logs. Edit your question to include the complete list of upgraded packages on that day.

Wait 37 minutes. Some shutdown task with a 30 minute timeout is waiting for something that isn't happening. When you come up, sudo journalctl  -b -1  -ex will tell you which.

I have edited my question with the needed logs.

I don't really understand why it was asked to me to update my question with some logs... to not reply afterwards.

Migrating to Ubuntu 24.04 did not help.
